# Creating Common Http service in angular

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http

I am new to Angular and I have created services for every component. The service is used to fetch data from server.

It was all working fine till my client has not told me to save the request offline and sync later on.

Now, I created a common service that will hit the server and get the data rather than existing component attached services.

I wanted to know whether this will effect any thing in the project or not.

If this approach is okay, then I will check the network connection in `CommonRequestService` and will save the request in DB.

Please check the code below and revert. I will be very thankful.

**Older Engineer Status Service**

```
export class engineerStatusService {
    constructor(public http: Http) {}
    // Post data to the server if user update the status
    post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable < any > {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });
        let data = body;
        let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        for (var key in body) {
            urlSearchParams.append(key, body[key]);
        }

        let bodyData = urlSearchParams.toString();
        return this.http.post(`${API_URL}${path}`, bodyData, options)
            .map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

**Updated Engineer Status Service**

Here the CommonRequestService is used.

```
export class engineerStatusService {
    constructor(private commonRequestService: CommonRequestService) {}
    // Post data to the server if user update the status
    post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable < Response > {
        let data = body;
        let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        for (var key in body) {
            urlSearchParams.append(key, body[key]);
        }
        let bodyData = urlSearchParams.toString();
        return this.commonRequestService.post(path, bodyData)
            .map(response => response.json())
    }
}
```

**CommonRequestService**

```
export class CommonRequestService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable < Response > {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });
        return this.http.post(`${API_URL}${path}`, body, options)
    }
}
```

**Engineer Status Component**

```
updateStatus(data) {
    this.engineerStatusService
        .post('status', data)
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, error => {
            console.log('Error occured =>', error);
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already did it, I guess you only need support, right ?

Because if you're willing to do it again, here are two leads for you :

1 - The [service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro), on recent browsers, that are very powerful

2 - [Http Interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses), that catch every request you make, and do something before processing them. This is the solution I recommend to you : it's powerful, built-in, and requires a lesser amount of code.

Comment: The Http Interceptors link opens the Service workers link only.

Important thing is once the data is fetched, the user can do any activity on the data in offline mode. No caching is required. I am thinking of saving the request and body data in a queue in database. Later on when the network is available. I can send all the data from the queue to the server.

My main question is whatever changes I have made whether they are okay or there will be any issue. Please help!

Comment: Sorry man, old keyboard, I edited that issue. What you're asking is still possible with Interceptors ! And about your code, I can't know, I should test it to see if it works ...

Comment: It would be great if you could test it. I don't want to do much rework as of now. This is my first project in Angular. With the next project I would see how service workers and Http Interceptors work. But for the time being, please check my code and let me know if I should proceed or not.

Comment: And how could I ? You have no caching system I can see, no offline mode either. All I see is you made a custom Http service (which is basically an home-made Interceptor, but anyways). So if you want to know, it's nasty, because you're not using what Angular has to offer, you rather make an imperfect custom service. If you're waiting for my approval, I won't give it to you, sorry :/

Comment: Firstly, I don't need page caching system. My app runs on Mobile browser iOS and android. For offline mode we have all data stored in Sqlite tables. 

Okay if I have written a custom Http Service as I am new to Angular. If Interceptor is the way to go, then I will see how I can use Interceptor. Also you mean to say, if there is no network, then from the interceptor I can store the request data in DB. Understand that this request is to update some status. If interceptor can store that request data and url in my table and this is from one place. Then thats the way to go.

Comment: Any comments on my reply ?

Comment: No, no comment. You wanted to have a feedback, I gave you one. If you're stubborn and don't accept it, then I don't need to comment just to read everytime "No" !